# Most Flexible .Net Collection

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I'm creating a `CustomControl` and I need my control has a collection that accept almost all kind of generic and none generic collection. For example `List<T>`, `IEnumerable` and etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `IEnumerable` is the base of every possible collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>` will accept most (possibly all) collections*.

<sub>* In fact, those are not, strictly speaking, collections – however, you mentioned `IEnumerable` in the question.</sub>

Comment: And since `IEnumerable<T>` already implements `IEnumerable`, using `IEnumerable` covers all the cases. But having a generic version is also nice.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Yes, it is rare (from what I have seen) for one to want a non-generic `IEnumerable`, hence the alternative...

Answer (score 2):

The universal collection interface is the non-generic `IEnumerable` interface.  Practically every collection authored since .NET 1.0 implements this interface.  If you want the maximum flexibility, this is the best choice.